Singular cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$
Let $X$ be a cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$. I need to prove that $X$ is either cone over a cubic curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$, or rational.
My attempt: Let $O$ be a singular point of $X$, consider the projection $\pi:X-O\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^3-O\to\mathbb{P}^2$ from $O$.
Consider the (scheme-theoretic) image $Y$ of $\pi$, then $Y$ is a curve or $\mathbb{P}^2$ itself.
If $Y$ is a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$, then $X$ must be the cone over $Y$. I have problem in the case $Y=\mathbb{P}^2$. I think that I need to show that $\pi$ is birational in this case.
For closed point $y\in \mathbb{P}^2$, let $L_y$ be the line joining $O$ and $Y$. $L_y$ intersect $X$ at $O$ with multiplicity$\geq2$ as $O$ is a singular point. The condition "$L_y$ intersect $X$ at $O$ with multiplicity$=3$" is a closed condition, hence the set-theoretic image of $\pi$ is an open subscheme $U$ of $\mathbb{P}^2$, whose closed points are bijective to closed points of $X-O$.
Now I want to show that $\pi$ induced an isomorphism $X-O\to U$, but I don't know how to treat this.

The map $X - O \to U$ need is not an isomorphism --- it contracts all lines on $X$ passing through $O$ (typically, 6 lines) to points in $\mathbb{P}^2$ (typically 6 points lying on a conic).
